# Add random date to safe.parse_datetime when there is an absence of date

Tags: sql, date, datetime, parsing, google-bigquery

What it looks like:

| unique_id | date_of_birth |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 197601 |
| 5678 | 198712 |

So only year and month are present, e.g 1976 and 01 in the example above.

I can safe.parse_datetime with "%Y%m" to get the below:

| unique_id | date_of_birth |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1976-01-01T00:00:00 |
| 5678 | 1987-12-01T:00:00:00 |

I'm happy with that including the time, but, I don't want the 1st as the date, I want the 15th for all of them. I can't quite work/out remember how to do this. So my desired output would be:

| unique_id | date_of_birth |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1976-01-15T00:00:00 |
| 5678 | 1987-12-15T:00:00:00 |

Comment: Do you need `SELECT DATE_ADD(what_you_have_now, INTERVAL 14 DAY) AS date_of_birth;`?

Comment: Not quite sure how that would work as I need to parse the existing string as date and time in the same process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, you can try below.

```sql
parse_datetime('%Y%m%d', date_of_birth || 15)
```

For example,

```sql
with sample_table as (
  select 1234 unique_id, '197601' date_of_birth union all
  select 5678, '198712'
)
select parse_datetime('%Y%m%d', date_of_birth || 15) from sample_table;

--Query results
+---------------------+
|         f0_         |
+---------------------+
| 1976-01-15T00:00:00 |
| 1987-12-15T00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: Perfect - I'd added the || 15 part but not the %d - mental block - thank you.